# Expo Go works with mobile data, but it doesn't with my house network

Tags: node.js, linux, react-native, ubuntu, expo

I just switched to Linux some days ago, and I'm setting up my development environment. I'm currently working with React Native and Expo. But I ran into a problem when running the command "npx expo start", when I'm in my house network the Expo Go App in my phone won't build the app, whereas when I'm with my mobile hotspot from my phone, it works perfect.

This happened to a friend of mine some months ago, I think it's related to the network's properties, I mean that it works with private networks, but it doesn't with public ones. But I don't know how to configure the connection from a Ubuntu-based linux distro PC.

I would appreciate the help.

Comment: "mobile data" and "mobile hotspot" are not the same thing.

Comment: And how to configure network on Ubuntu isn't on-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone and your computer need to be on the same network, and you need to specify in the Expo Go app the IP address of your PC.  The Expo Go app will not automatically start on your phone just by running `npx expo start` on your desktop, but you can [use the QR code](https://docs.expo.dev/get-started/expo-go/#install-expo-go-on-your-device) ***if*** the font in your terminal allows the phone to recognize the QR code.

The Expo docs do have a section on [troubleshooting when your device cannot connect](https://docs.expo.dev/get-started/create-a-project/#is-the-app-not-loading-on-your).